# Можно ли строку переделать в пример

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
a = input('Введите пример') # Например 2+2*2
```

Можно ли что бы программа обработала строку и вывела ответ ?

Answer (score 1):

```
a = input('Введите пример')
print(eval(a))
```

Comment: Можно ещё обработать исключения с помощью try, except